# Can I set up a virtual directory on Windows that links to a directory on Ubuntu?

Tags: server, windows, 12.10, virtualization

Is it possible to create a virtual directory in windows that links to a directory on an Ubuntu 12.10 server?

If so, how?

I'd like to do it this way because it slows me down to constantly save & upload via ftp.  I'm trying to develop a websocket++ server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443732/how-do-i-mount-a-remote-linux-folder-in-windows-through-ssh), which is incomplete.

With the latest version of WinSCP, you can "synchronize directories".  It's easy to set up.